# Unable to log in using FBLoginView in iOS using facebook sdk

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

The function `loginViewShowingLoggedInUser` is never getting called. Even when I press the Log in Button, it goes to the facebook screen asking me to press OK and it comes back and still shows "Log in.." in the button. Each time only the `loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser` function gets called.

Below is my class:

```
import UIKit

class FBLoginViewController: UIViewController, FBLoginViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var fbLoginView: FBLoginView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.fbLoginView.delegate = self
    self.fbLoginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]

}

func loginViewShowingLoggedInUser(loginView: FBLoginView!) {
    println("in loginViewShowingLoggedInUser")
}

func loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser(loginView: FBLoginView!) {
    println("in loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser")

}

func loginView(loginView: FBLoginView!, handleError error: NSError!) {
    println("in loginView")
}

func loginViewFetchedUserInfo(loginView: FBLoginView!, user: FBGraphUser!) {
    println("in loginViewFetchedUserInfo")
}
}
```

Even after hitting ok on the facebook screen, it returns to screen as "Log in..."

[image: Image showing confirmation of facebook login]

[image: Image showing still the Log In button, expecting Log Out]

Comment: make sure you have added delegate in AppDelegate.m file.
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 4.X Facebook has split the SDK in 3 parts:

> The SDK is now composed of three frameworks, FBSDKCoreKit,  FBSDKLoginKit, and FBSDKShareKit.

So if you are using the latest SDK use FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate instead of FBLoginViewDelegate. For custom login UI you can use FBSDKLoginManager.

See the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3) for more.